# How can I change the default widgets and icons on the home screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-source

I have a custom Android ROM which I am compiling from source. I would like to modify which widgets and app icons are present on the home screen by default.

How would I go about doing this? A hint to where the configuration file is in the source code would be sufficient.

**EDIT**

It looks like the configuration for this is in `res/xml` in the `Launcher3` application, but none of those configurations matches what is being displayed, and when I modify any of them nothing changes.

Comment: changing default_workspace.xml files in `res/xml` worked for me, I was able to remove Gallery icon from home screen. Please submit your answer, I'll upvote it )) It was actually Trebuchet app being used as Launcher3 in CM

Comment: I think this worked for me too and I just had to wipe the `/userdata` partition. Although I can't remember too well because this was a long time ago. I posted it as an answer, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the configuration for this is in `res/xml` in the Launcher3 application.